# Transition AlertDialog from showing message to ListView adapter?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to start an AlertDialog with 2 buttons (basic confirmation dialog) then transition it to showing items in the adapter I passed to it. When I create the dialog with `AlertDialog.Builder` I use `setMessage` and `setAdapter` with an `ArrayAdapter` that is initially empty. When the positive button is clicked, ideally I want to smoothly transition to hiding the buttons and showing 2 items in the ListView. I set the message to null, manipulate the buttons, and add 2 objects to the ArrayAdapter. Yay, except for the fact that AlertController#setupContent does this nice thing:

```
    if (mMessage != null) {
        mMessageView.setText(mMessage);
    } else {
        mMessageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mScrollView.removeView(mMessageView);

        if (mListView != null) {
            final ViewGroup scrollParent = (ViewGroup) mScrollView.getParent();
            final int childIndex = scrollParent.indexOfChild(mScrollView);
            scrollParent.removeViewAt(childIndex);
            scrollParent.addView(mListView, childIndex,
                    new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
            ....
```

Does anyone have any way to hack this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is curious, I did come up with a hack. I used the concept of header views in `ListView` to change states between 1) using a TextView as header, 2) using a ProgressBar as header, 3) no header. I manipulated `dialog.listView` from the dialog's `onStart`. In my adapter I had the notion of initially being empty, then passing it the data once loaded, and it calls `notifyDatasetChanged`. I even used a LayoutTransition to animate!

I had to hardcode some paddings of the message because the constants the dialog normally uses are buried in `alert_dialog.xml` or something. If anyone is curious, I can post a gist with some code.

I did think of another solution, that is probably a similar amount of code, but more reusable and readable: implement a custom View that switches between a message, a ProgressBar indicator and a RecyclerView, and set an instance of the view as the dialog's "custom view".